# Using gmp with shell-escape in Windows 10, MiKTeX 2.9, WinEdt 9.1

Tags: miktex, winedt, shell-escape

Windows 10, MiKTeX 2.9 64-bit, WinEdt Build: 20150731  (v. 9.1) - 64-bit. I have updated the filename database and all format files in MiKTex 2.9.

I am using the gmp package that allows MetaPost files to be part of your latex document. In order to use the package it is necessary to put EnableWrite18=t in your pdflatex.ini file. Adding --enable-write18 or --shell-escape in WinEdt did not work (separate issue, possibly). However, once I click on the pdftexify button in WinEdt and the compilation encounters a MetaPost file generated by gmp, a panel pops up saying that Metapost has stopped working. Everything seems to load properly--the .mp and .mpx files are there, but MetaPost crashes. Does anyone know what might be the problem? Here is a MWE for those wishing to try it out.

```
    \documentclass[10pt]{article}
    \usepackage{amsmath}
    %% use option 'nowrite' if graphics are stable
    \usepackage[shellescape,latex]{gmp}
    \usempxclass{article}
    \usempxpackage{amsmath}
    \setlength{\unitlength}{1cm}
    \begin{document}

    \begin{mpost}[name=mwe]
    numeric u; u:=1.0cm;
    draw (0,0)*u--(1,0)*u;
    label(\btex "A" etex, (0,0)*u);
    label(\btex "B" etex, (1,0)*u);
    \end{mpost}

    \usempost[width=4.0in]{mwe}

    \end{document}
```

Comment: I've just tried with `pdflatex` annd it works fine . You can't can't use  `pdftexify` as it is not a plain tex document, but mrobably `pdflatexify`. Unfortunately, there is no line concerning `pdflatexify` in WinEdt's`Execution modes`. I suggest you use `pdflatex` first (with option `--write18`) and use the gmp option `nowrite`, with `pdflatexify` once the figures have all been made.

Comment: Btw, welcome to TeX SX!

Answer (score 7):

As clearly stated in `pdflatex.ini`:

> please do not edit this file

so revert your changes in that file and rebuild the format.

You should enable the `--shell-escape` feature when invoking your compiler.

To do that in WinEdt, if you wish to use the PDFTeXify compiler, go to Options -> Execution Modes, and add `--tex-option=--shell-escape` in the "Switches" field of this compiler, as in the image below.

[image]

If instead you want do that for PDFLaTeX, you can simply add `--shell-escape` in the corresponding field.

[image]

The `--tex-option` part is needed because PDFTeXify calls MiKTeX's `texify.exe` executable which requires that format.

Now your code should compile fine with this output:

[image]

Comment: I used a suggestion elsewhere to execute the command

Comment: I used a suggestion elsewhere to execute the command "initexmf --edit-config-file=miktex\config\pdflatex.ini" and then add "EnableWrite18=t". There was no line in the pdflatex.ini that said "Do not edit this file" so it must have been a local copy. I added the switches as you suggested and at least I have shell escape now. However, the problem still persists. Is there anything in Windows 10 security settings that might be a problem? I also apologize for using quotes instead of $ and label instead of label.bot, for example, in my MWE MetaPost example.

Comment: @W.Kehowski It is always better not to set `--shell-escape` permanently. In this way you can always go to Execution Modes and revert this. In regards of your MetaPost error, I don't know where it comes from. Try opening the file `yourfile+mp0001.mp` in WinEdt and running MetaPost on it to see what happens.

Comment: It still crashes. Aargh!

Comment: @W.Kehowski Try removing the packages `miktex-metapost-base` and `miktex-metapost-bin` and then reinstall them.

Comment: I tried that and it still doesn't work. I was only able to reinstall miktex-metapost-bin-x64-2.9 since miktex-metapost-base no longer shows up in the package manager. I tried synchronizing with my install directory and it still doesn't show up. I also updated fndb and formats. And restarting the computer.

Comment: @W.Kehowski That's the cause of the problem. Change package repository and sinchronize. You have to install `miktex-metapost-base-2.7` otherwise all MetaPost base files are not installed in your system.

Comment: Too late. The 2.7 version did not appear or I would have installed it. I installed the 64-bit MiKTeX on two of my older machines without 3+monitor capability and MetaPost still crashed. I switched to 32-bit MiKTeX and now MetaPost doesn't crash. Yay! And thank you for your help!