# How to use Tikz/Pgfplots to plot an algebraic curve on a restricted domain?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, plot

I want to plot for example equation `y^2 x + x^3-3y^2-2x^2+x=0`. But at the same time I need to gray out some parts of the plane (see shaded area). Is there a way to do this?  [image]

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by deleting parts of the plane?

Comment: See pgfplots manual regarding domain.

Comment: @percusse like in the picture

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have a `tikz`/`pgfplot` solution:

```
\documentclass[border=15pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}\pgfplotsset{compat=1.13}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,positioning,calc,patterns}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    thick]
        \begin{axis}[
            xmin=-3, xmax=6, 
            ymin=-5, ymax=5,
            axis x line = center, 
            axis y line = center,
            xtick = \empty,
            ytick = \empty,
            xlabel = {$x$},
            ylabel = {$y$},
            legend style = {nodes=right},
            legend pos = north east,
            clip mode = individual,
            ]
            \addplot[red, samples=100, domain=0:2.6] {(x-1)*sqrt(x/(3-x))};
            \addplot[red, samples=100, domain=0:2.6] {-(x-1)*sqrt(x/(3-x))};
            \draw [dashed] (3,-5) -- (3,5);
            \path [pattern=north west lines, pattern color = gray] 
                (3.1, -5+0.1) rectangle (5.5, 5-0.1);
            \path [pattern=north west lines, pattern color = gray] 
                (-2.9, -5+0.1) rectangle (-0.1, 5-0.1);
            \path (0,0) node [below left] {$O$};
            \path (1,0) node [below] {$A$};
            \filldraw [fill=white] (3,0) circle(1pt) node [below right]{3};
            \path (2.6, 5-.5) node[fill=white, above] {$tg_{Y_\infty}$};
        \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Output]

You can adjust colors, labels etc as you want. Notice that if you use a `pgfplots` older than 1.11 (I think) you have to add `axis cs:` to all the drawing and path coordinates in the `axis` environment.

If you want to use the implicit form of the equation, you can use the `contour gnuplot` option (see this example on the [gnuplot side](http://gnuplot-surprising.blogspot.com.es/2011/09/assume-three-is-equation-fxygxy-and-we.html) and the [section 4.6 of the pgfplots manual](http://pgfplots.sourceforge.net/pgfplots.pdf)):

```
\documentclass[border=15pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}\pgfplotsset{compat=1.13}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,positioning,calc,patterns}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    thick]
        \begin{axis}[
            xmin=-3, xmax=6, 
            ymin=-5, ymax=5,
            axis x line = center, 
            axis y line = center,
            axis line style = {thick, gray},
            xtick = \empty,
            ytick = \empty,
            xlabel = {$x$},
            every axis x label/.append style = {below, gray},
            ylabel = {$y$},
            every axis y label/.append style = {above left, gray},
            legend style = {nodes=right},
            legend pos = north east,
            clip mode = individual,
            view = {0}{90},    
        ]
        \addplot3[contour gnuplot={
                levels=0, labels=false,
            }, 
            samples=100,
            ] 
            {y*y*x + x*x*x -3*y*y-2*x*x+x};
            \draw [dashed] (3,-5) -- (3,5);
            \path [pattern=north west lines, pattern color = gray] 
                (3.1, -5+0.1) rectangle (5.5, 5-0.1);
            \path [pattern=north west lines, pattern color = gray] 
                (-2.9, -5+0.1) rectangle (-0.1, 5-0.1);
            \path (0,0) node [below left] {$O$};
            \path (1,0) node [below] {$A$};
            \filldraw [fill=white] (3,0) circle(1pt) node [below right]{3};
            \path (2.6, 5-.5) node[fill=white, above] {$tg_{Y_\infty}$};
        \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

You have to run it with `-shell-escape` (or  `--enable-write18`) flag to `pdflatex`, and be patient... (it's really slow):

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Is perfect. But there are no ways to plot that equation directly with his equation? @Rmano

Comment: I suppose you can use gnuplot plot type and  http://gnuplot-surprising.blogspot.com.es/2011/09/assume-three-is-equation-fxygxy-and-we.html - never tried really .

Comment: @AndreaLeo, see my edit...

Comment: @Rmano It is an old story but I have Package pgfplots Error: sorry, plot file{curve_contourtmp0.table} could not be opened. What you suggest to do with this? I compliled with WinEdt PDFTeXify and PDFLaTeX.

Comment: @EvgenyKuznetsov this could happen if you did not enable `shell-escape` (see for example https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/262442/38080) or if you do not have `gnuplot` installed. But these are just wild guesses...

Comment: @Rmano I am  trying to manage that, yet not successfully :) Does gnuplot work in overleaf?

Comment: @EvgenyKuznetsov I know nothing of overleaf, sorry. If you post a new question about that, I know that at least one of the overlef's developer is very active here.

Answer (score 4):

As there's no solution so far with Tikz/pgf, I propose an easy solution with `pstricks`. It's compilable with `pdflatex` if you launch it with the `--enable-write18` switch (for MiKTeX) or `-shell-escape` (TeX Live, MacTeX). Alternatively, you can compile with `XeLaTeX`.

```
\documentclass[x11names, border=3pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{fourier} 
\usepackage{pst-plot}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}

\begin{document}

\psset{algebraic, unit=1.5, arrowinset=0.12, arrowsize=4pt, linejoin=1, plotstyle=curve, plotpoints=200}

\begin{pspicture*}(-3, -4)(6, 4.5)
\psaxes[linecolor=LightSteelBlue3, ticks=none,  labels=none,  arrows=-> ](0,0)(-3, -4)(6, 4)[$x$,-135] [$y$,120]
\psset{linewidth=1.2pt, linecolor=IndianRed3, plotpoints=100}
\begin{psclip}{\psframe[linestyle=none](0,-3.9)(3,3.9)}
\psplot{0}{2.6}{(x-1)*sqrt(x/(3-x))}
\psplot{0}{2.6}{(1-x)*sqrt(x/(3-x))}
\end{psclip}
\psdot(1,0)\uput[d](1,0){$ 1 $}
\psset{linestyle=dashed, dash=4pt 4pt, linecolor=LightSteelBlue3}
\psdot[dotstyle=o](3,0)
\psline[linewidth=0.4pt](3, -4)(3, 4) % asymptote
\uput[u](3,4){$tg_{Y_\infty}$}
\psset{linestyle=none,  fillstyle=vlines,  hatchwidth=0.4pt, framesep=1pt}
\psframe(-3,-3.9)(-0.1,3.9)
\psframe(3.1,-3.9)(5.7,3.9)
\uput[dr](3,0){\psframebox*{$ 3 $}}
\uput[dl](0,0){\psframebox*{$O$}}
\end{pspicture*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That makes a lot more sense. I'll delete my comments