# Plot Algebraic Curves with TikZ/PGFPlots

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

Is there a way to plot this curve

```
    x^2y^2-x^2-3xy+2=0
```

using TikZ or PGFPlots using exaclty the equation given in order to have something like that?

[image]

Comment: Shouldn't tikz or pgfplots support that kind of equation, you can tell tikz to compute the points with gnuplot and then plot the result.

Comment: You already asked that kind of question http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/312675/95441. Where is the difference to your old question?

Comment: There is no the answere that I need today. I need to plot the curve with 1 equation.

Comment: why can't you separate as two equations for y and plot the two curves on the same axis, I don't know whether pgfplots can do that but why does it matter if it can't you can do it by hand or with other software before plotting.

Comment: Is http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18359/plotting-an-implicit-function-using-pgfplots helpful?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I already mentioned in the [comment below the question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/347220/plot-algebraic-curves-with-tikzpicture#comment852293_347220) I don't see anything new here compared to [your other question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/312675/95441). And as David already mentioned in [his comment below the question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/347220/plot-algebraic-curves-with-tikzpicture#comment852301_347220) what should be so bad to just draw two `\addplot`s? If this would be an option, you could do the following. (I think adding the shaded areas should not be a problem for you.)

Please have a look at the comments in the code for more details.

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            % set some appropriate y min and max values
            ymin=-5,
            ymax=5,
            % increase the number of samples so the corresponding calculated y values
            % are at minimum in the given y range AND the value at x = 0 is calculated
            samples=101,
            % just to be sure, plot the lines smoothly
            smooth,
            axis lines=middle,
            % we don't need any x ticks
            xtick=\empty,
            % draw horizontal lines for asymptotes ...
            % https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=asymptotes+x%5E2y%5E2-x%5E2-3xy%2B2%3D0
            ytick={-1,1},
            grid=major,
            % ... but we don't need any labels at them
            yticklabels={,},
            % print x and y labels
            xlabel=$x$,
            ylabel=$y$,
            % move the y label to "the other side" so it is not overlapping
            % with the plots
            ylabel style={
                anchor=north east,
            },
            % to filter away the zero values
            unbounded coords=jump,
            x filter/.expression={x==0 ? NaN : x},
        ]
            % solve the equation x^2y^2-x^2-3xy+2=0 with Wolfram Alpha ...
            % https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Solve%5Bx%5E2y%5E2-x%5E2-3xy%2B2%3D0,+y%5D
            % ... and draw them in the same style
            \addplot [red] {(3*x - sqrt(4*x^4 + x^2))/(2*x^2)};
            \addplot [red] {(3*x + sqrt(4*x^4 + x^2))/(2*x^2)};

            % find the values for y = 0 and add some nodes
            % https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Solve%5Bx%5E2y%5E2-x%5E2-3xy%2B2%3D0,+y%3D0%5D
            \addplot [only marks] coordinates {(-sqrt(2),0) (sqrt(2),0)}
                node [at start,above right] {$A_1$}
                node [at end,below left]    {$A_2$}
            ;
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]