# standalone produce strange output

Tags: xetex, standalone

[image]

its a chinese cls thesis template with xelatex, miktex on windows 10

if i use input, the produced pdf is correct
if i use `\includestandalone`,out put has 4 strange numbers?
both produce no separate pdf for the figure

```
\documentclass[doctor,euler,twoside,openright]{ustcthesis}
\usepackage[mode=buildmissing, build={quote={<char>}}]{standalone}

\begin{center}
\input{ch1/mod1alignvl}
\includestandalone[mode=buildmissing, width=\textwidth]{ch1/mod1alignvl}
\end{center}
```

why no standalone pdf? thanks you for any help

Update--------------------------------
After help from @Marijn change quote={} to quote={'} and remove \input. and run XeLaTeX with --shell-escape separate pdf produced but it is corrupted！the input pdf and the main pdf look like this ：
[image]

[image]

change another input file also corrupted！
[image]

the good news is that the four strange numbers in the main pdf disappear！
but the input file produce corrupted tikz drawing though i have not change anything inside the input tikz！great thanks to anyone help on how to fix this?

Final Update -----------------------------
Solved！the corruption is because i put tikzlibrary inclusion in the main file！and the missing of includegraphics is also because i did not put \graphicspath{{figures/}} in the inner file！so inside tikz cannot find the figure files！Thank @Marijn for so kindly help!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. I can't reproduce the problem currently. I downloaded the class from https://github.com/ustctug/ustcthesis/blob/master/ustcthesis.cls, I used a different `.tex` file to include (because I don't have your file) and I modified your code slightly to add `\begin{document}` and `\end{document}`, change `quote={<char>}` to `quote={'}` and remove `\input`. Then I run XeLaTeX with `--shell-escape` and the standalone file is included without the numbers, and a separate pdf file is produced.

Comment: Maybe there is some error that you have ignored (`quote={<char>}` results in an error for sure, also `\input` of a file with its own documentclass will fail)? If you ignore errors then the output after that can be unpredictable. Or maybe the included file already exists as a pdf with the numbers on it (`buildmissing` doesn't recreate the file if it already exists)? Please try with a very simple file for `\includestandalone` to see if the same problem occurs in that case, if not then the problem is somewhere in your included file and you need to share the source of that file in your question.

Comment: @Marijn Thank you so much for even downloading the template！Sorry for being Late，I will try your suggestion and report back to you if it works as soon as possible ❥(^_-)

Comment: @Marjin still no pdf after change quote={<char>} to quote={'}，but i do not know how to run xelatex with options --shell-escape，i only run xelatex，is this the cause of my problem？can you be kindly telling me how to config compiler options，i am using  winedit with miktex

Comment: @Marijn simple input files also no pdf produced！so it should not be relevant with the inside file

Comment: I don't have Winedt myself but there is supposed to be a `Switches` field in the `Options`-`Execution modes` menu where you can set `--shell-escape` for XeLaTeX, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/262442/ for an illustration.

Comment: @Marijn thank you so much pdf produced after adding --shell-escape and 4 strange numbers disappear! but the produced pdf is corrupted i have not change anything inside! what would be the cause of this strange drawing output of inside tikz?

Comment: @Marijn Thank you again the problem is finally solved！there is really something wrong with my inside file！i did not put necessary config command inside only put them outside cause the bug！Now it is well produced with no bug！(๑′ᴗ‵๑)Ｉ Lᵒᵛᵉᵧₒᵤ❤